# Wireless 802.11ac and New MacBook Air

Tags: macbook-pro, airport, 802.1x

Just bought the new MacBook Air, 13" and the new AirPort Extreme Base Station. I am curious as to how I get the max connection? Option + Click on my WiFi shows I am connected only using "n" and on the 2.4Ghz frequency. Why would it not be on "ac" and 5Ghz?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://store.apple.com/us/question/answers/readonly/can-i-turn-off-80211n-and-just-use-80211g-on-airport-extreme/QUX4XFATK9PTUT2T2) can help? Hold down the option key when selecting the radio mode in Airport Utility in order to view more options - such as forcing an "ac only" mode.

Comment: That might help but would prevent other devices that don't support "ac" to connect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Operating at 5GHz means that (in the margin - there are other factors) 802.11ac will penetrate walls, ceilings, floors **less well** than 802.11n at 2.4GHz.

The AirPort Utility allows you to setup a separate Network Name for the 5GHz frequency (Wireless Tab / Click Wireless Options). This means that you can explicitly select whether to connect a device via n/2.4GHz or ac/5GHz.

If you do this you can use **/System/Library/CoreServices/Wireless Diagnostics**  (via Option+Click on WiFi) described here: [How to troubleshoot 802.11ac bandwidth problems](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/93815/how-to-troubleshoot-802-11ac-bandwidth-problems) (note don't continue with the default assistant - select Utilities from the Window menu) to examine the relative performance of ac/n from different locations.

In my case I observed that with clear line of sight ac reported a Tx Rate of 867 Mbps compared to 145 Mbps for n. In contrast, several rooms away ac dropped off to the extent that n had better performance.

Reverting the changes above (so both 2.4GHz and 5GHz have the same network name) and repeating the tests, saw the connection automatically switch from ac to n as signal dropped off.

In contrast, I've not (yet) seen an automatic switch from n to ac at a location where powering Wifi off/on gets (and holds) the ac connection.

While less than perfect in terms of "just doing the right thing", this is perhaps understandable - triggering a switch when quality drops below some threshold rather than continuously looking for a "better" connection when what you've got (albeit n rather than ac) is rated as "excellent". Of course this is an OS X behaviour ... perhaps Mavericks will address it?

Comment: nice insight, that was exactly what I asked couple a days ago in another question on Super User which got closed because of ambiguity

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is still happening with a mid-2015 MacBook Pro 15" and OS X 10.11.5.

Apparently, this is in spec:

https://discussions.apple.com/message/23356016

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be a global problem affecting a lot of new MacBook Air. You may need to wait a software update.

[On Cult of Mac](http://www.cultofmac.com/232716/new-macbook-air-owners-having-tons-of-problems-with-802-11ac-wifi)

Comment: A comment would be nice when downvoting.